# PromQL to find the number of timeouts/failures across all instances over a period of time

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, promql, resilience4j

Spring-boot application exposing the metrics, `resilience4j_timelimiter_calls_total`, seems to be counter, which is giving me the total timeouts happened till the current time.`

I have used `sum by (service, name) (rate(resilience4j_timelimiter_calls_total{service="service-name"}[5m]))` to find the number of timeouts happening over 5m.

I want to find total number of failures of the downstream API in say x time-period, including both timeouts and 4xx/5xx exceptions, meaning the number of times the resilience4j circuit breaker directed the call to fallback method.

> Is there a promethues exposed resilience metrics to find this ?

Answer (score 0):

> [`rate`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector.

Based on your description I believe you actually need [`increase`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase). It will calculate a total increase of metric over range provided.

You query would be

```
sum by (service, name) (increase(resilience4j_timelimiter_calls_total{service="service-name"}[5m]))
```

Comment: How to find the total number of failures of the downstream API over a time period, that includes timeouts as well. Is there a metric for this ?

Comment: @tusharRawat, that depends on exporter you're using. I'm not familiar with resilience4j, all I can advise you, is to look into documentation of in, specifically - description of exposed metrics.